# What is a modular tensor category / functor?

Tags: mathematical-physics, research-level, topological-order, topological-phase, category-theory

I have reads several answers here about this notion, especially regarding topological order, see *e.g.* [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/161276/16689), but this notion sounds completely new for me. Also, I found nothing really helpful on the net.

Could someone give me some basic intuition of what is a [modular tensor category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+tensor+category), and it's use in term of topological order?

Any accessible reference introducing this concept is welcome.

Comment: I think the short answer for this is to see [Kitaev](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) and [Bakalov-Kirillov](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html). The book of [Wang](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~zhenghwa/data/course/cbms.pdf) is also good.